# Setting URI to root directory in application for image source

Tags: c#, wpf

How do you set the URI for an image source to the root directory (i.e. same folder as your exe) in a WPF application?

```
var myImage = new Image();
myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/speedline.png", UriKind.Absolute));
```

I've tried the above and keep getting the following error message:

*An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll.
Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'AssemblyName, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.*

I am obviously doing something very wrong, but can guarantee that the png file can be found at `C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Speedy\Speedy\bin\Debug`, in the same folder as my exe file, but how do I reference it?

Comment: Is your assembly really named `AssemblyName`? Because project name seems to be `Speedy` from the debug folder path.

Comment: @icebat no it isn't, its called Speedy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a new folder under the solution explorer called component and add the existing image under that. Now try using the Relative path.

```
myImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/component/speedline.png", UriKind.Relative));
```